# Finding the port for a 1905 arrival to United States?

Tags: united-states, immigration, scotland, manifest, 1900s-decade

My grandfather John Gibson Gowans immigrated the second time to the United States from Scotland on a ship called The Caledonia in 1905.

This was his 2nd time as his parents first immigrated in 1888 when he was 1 year old and then returned back to Scotland.  My grandfather was 18 when he returned with 8 siblings.  James, Margaret, Alexander, Janet, George, Charles, William and Mary.  Where did they land in the United States?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to G&FH SE. If you know the ship's name and the year, you should be able to find the passenger list which will include the arrival port (ie where they landed). Do you need beginners help in where to access passenger lists or have you looked on the usual sites and need help crafting a better search? Do you suspect that your information may be flawed?

Comment: Did he naturalise? That often gives such details.

Answer (score 1):

They came into the Port of New York on 23 July 1905 on the Caledonia. If you have an Ancestry account you can find the passenger ship list [here](https://www.ancestry.com/imageviewer/collections/7488/images/NYT715_602-0606). Or you can find it by searching on [statueofliberty.org](https://heritage.statueofliberty.org/passenger) for Janet Gowans.